# Regarding cql filter

Tags: java, gis, cql, ogc

I want to bring a parcel highlighted with given coordinates from the following URL

http://gistest:8080/rest/Spatial/WMS?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG:28355&BBOX=308998,5815926,309179,5816121&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=800&CQL_FILTER=Parcel=100936&layers=PARCEL_Test&Styles=&FORMAT=image/png

Except the cql filter everything else is working fine.it is not throwing any error but it is not working either.

I checked the web.xml file it does not have any filters like cql or ogc. if I have to add that in .xml file what should I write in java class,is not there in built class to use these filters?I’m new to gis.

It would be great, if some one can help me in this.

Cheers,
S C

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the attributes of the layer you are querying it is hard to be sure but the most likely issue is that attribute names are case sensitive so your filter may be missing if the attribute is `PARCEL` or more likely `parcel`.

A quick way to test if your filter is valid is to go to the [layer preview](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/layerpreview.html) if you open the menu at the top you can enter CQL and OGC filters to test them.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I'll check it.